# iOS crash: `com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT): required condition is false: NULL != engine`

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, speech, avaudioengine

Our application uses speech recognition with `.confirmation` task hint. With the advent of iOS 16, the app starts crashing with `com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT): required condition is false: NULL != engine` error. This mostly happened on the iPhone SE 2gen. Does anyone else have the same problem or have experience with a solution?

I already implement the audio engen stops, removing inpud node, all error handlers, put recognition request and recognition task in properties and set them to nil with audio engen stop. But the application continues to crash.

Comment: It really depends on your code. Please try to post any code which is involved in setting up your speech recogniser. Most likely you cleared or set `nil` the AVAudioEngine prematurely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it is already answered but on the Apple forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/44833